# How to await for multiple tasks when using lambda exp on the event handler

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, lambda, async-await

I have 2 classes Main.cs and Processing.cs (P and M for short) class M makes a call to P passing an html link, P in tern downloads, converts to Base64, renames and saves the file then returns a string back to M, now i need M to wait until all of this is complete to proceed but i have not been able to.

I  used a lambda expression with the event handler to be able to do everything in that function as opposed to a separate function for the event trigger so i would be able to return the string with the Base64 converted file, but it just returns the empty string, not wait until it has been assigned.

I thought the taskA.Wait() call would make it wait until all processing was done, but it's not the case

If anyone has any ideas I would appreciate the help.

the call from Main.cs is like this:

```
Processing processing = new processing();
String _link = “http://www.something.com”;
var ResultBase64_Val = processing.FileToBase64(_link).Result;
```

In Processing.cs the function is:

```
public async Task<String> FileToBase64(String filePath)
{
    String convertedFile = "";

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Task taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => client.OpenReadCompleted += async (object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) =>
     {   
           byte[] buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length];
           buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length];
           await e.Result.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
           convertedFile = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
     });
     client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(filePath));
     taskA.Wait();

     return convertedFile;           
    }
```

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Im using .NET Framework 4.5.1 installed with Windows 8.1
In regards to ur previous comment, i thought task meant everything in the block not just the `OpenReadComplete` event.
I went for async `WebClient` method cause it's wp8 app and with mobile net is not always stable, so async seemed safer, am i correct?

Comment: Consider using `System.Security.Cryptography.ToBase64Transform` instead of `Convert.ToBase64String` (see [ToBase64Transform on MSDN for examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tobase64transform(v=vs.110).aspx)). It will let you work with the stream directly instead of creating a byte array in memory. Or throw an exception if the response is larger than some upper bound you decide  on based on your expected usage.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz that would not solve the issue of getting the task to wait until d/l is complete and converted...
and besides these are images, do i think it would make a difference?

Comment: that's why I added a comment instead of putting it in an answer :) I would say that using a `Stream` instead of a huge byte array is even *more* important if you're downloading binary data (images). If you stream the data from the request to the endpoint (like a file) you'll only have to keep the two stream's buffers in memory (likely ~ 4KB) instead of the whole response (images on the web are usually in the 100's of KBs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the task started with `Task.Factory.StartNew` completes instantly, well before `OpenReadCompleted` is fired sometime in the future. That said, wrapping a naturally asynchronous API like `OpenReadAsync` with `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` is a bad idea anyway. Even if you waited for the event somehow, or used synchronous `OpenRead`, you'd be wasting a pool thread.

There's new [`WebClient.OpenReadTaskAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159420%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for that:

```
public async Task<String> FileToBase64(String filePath)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    using (var stream = await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(new Uri(filePath)))
    {
        // use stream.ReadAsync
    }
}
```

I also recommend `HttpClient` over `WebClient`, the former supports multiple HTTP requests in parallel:

```
using System.Net.Http;

// ...

public async Task<String> FileToBase64(String filePath)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(filePath))
    using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
        return string.Empty;
        // use stream.ReadAsync
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting errors `Error 3 'System.Net.WebClient' does not contain a definition for 'OpenReadTaskAsync' and no extension method 'OpenReadTaskAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.WebClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I presume it's a .Net Ver issue, I'm using Ver 4.5.1

Comment: @BobMachine, it's certainly [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159420%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) since .NET 4.5. Make sure you have `using System.Net;` statement on top of your source file.

Comment: @BobMachine Make sure your project(s) are set to build using .NET 4.5 (right-click on project, go to **Application** tab, change **Target framework** to **.NET Framework 4.5**)

Comment: @Noseratio this is a windows phone 8 App, and that's what is shows on the target drop down. Could that be the reason?

It's weird couse I'm even getting an error on the first `using`...
and i do have `using System.Net`

Comment: @BobMachine, indeed it appears `OpenReadTaskAsync` is not implemented in WP8 .NET API. Use `HttpClient` instead, I've updated my answer with  a sample.

Comment: @Noseratio Bummer now I’m getting another error, on the 3rd using

`Error 4 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.IO.Stream>': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable’`

Comment: @BobMachine Just remove the `using` statement surrounding the stream.

Comment: @BobMachine, I made a typo, `await` was missing: `using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())`.

Comment: @Noseratio yes that fixed the errors, but it's not doing anything, nothing coming out on the `debug` I'm using similar code inside that block.
Was there something i need to do. I was trying to pass the stream to the array byte[]

Comment: @BobMachine, you can use [`ReadAsByteArrayAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasbytearrayasync(v=vs.110).aspx) directly. However I think there's a problem somewhere else, e.g., with the URL resource. First, make sure the same URL and the same `FileToBase64` works as expected from a Desktop app. Do the unit testing.

Comment: @Noseratio if i change to `using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync())` i get that weird error with the `using` the url and FileToBase64 work as expected, it was working fine b4 just for the fact i couldn't get the task to wait until all was complete., the d/l and conversion.
It's like it's not even going inside the `using` block, what u just posted

Comment: @Noseratio thank you it works perfectly, it was my mistake, i didn't have await on the call, silly me.
I had it expecting a string before where as now it's a  `Task`
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the WebClient, and you want to return result from the method, you'll want to use the TaskCompletionSource and subscribe to the event normally

```
public Task<String> FileToBase64(String filePath)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<string> completion = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    String convertedFile = "";

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.OpenReadCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        TextReader reader = new StreamReader(e.Result);
        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        completion.SetResult(result);
    };
    client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(filePath));

    return completion.Task;
}
```

Given this answer, I would recommend using the HttpClient instead of the WebClient

Comment: you sample code did not work, i don't get any errors but it's not d/l the image files from URL.

I tried using the `TaskCompletionSource` with what i had b4 but it's not working either.

Comment: what is returned? What is the value of result?

Comment: sorry it actually works, it was my mistake, i didn't have await on the call, I forgot to put it couse before it had it expecting a string, which was causing an error.

It downloads properly but the `Convert.ToBase64()` is giving me an odd result, just a series of `AAAA..`

Answer (score 2):

Both [Noseratio answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21868363/2681948) and [Shawn Kendrot answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21868189/2681948) should work. But I will try to use other approach - by `WebRequest`.

First to do this I will have to extend my WebRequest method by `GetRequestStreamAsync()` - WP lacks this method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
  public static Task<Stream> GetRequestStreamAsync(this WebRequest webRequest)
  {
    TaskCompletionSource<Stream> taskComplete = new TaskCompletionSource<Stream>();
    webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(arg =>
    {
        try
        {
            Stream requestStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(arg);
            taskComplete.TrySetResult(requestStream);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { taskComplete.SetException(ex); }
    }, webRequest);
    return taskComplete.Task;
  }
}
```

Then I would convert your Task to something like this:

```
public async Task<string> FileToBase64(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
       WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(filePath));
       if (request != null)
       {
           using (Stream resopnse = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
           using (MemoryStream temp = new MemoryStream())
           {
               const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
               byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

               int bytesread = 0;
               while ((bytesread = await resopnse.ReadAsync(buf, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
                     temp.Write(buf, 0, bytesread);

               return Convert.ToBase64String(temp.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return String.Empty;
   }
   catch { return String.Empty; }
}
```

Maybe this will help.

Comment: Thank you, you were correct both solutions work, but getting an odd result on `Convert.ToBase64()` on Shawn Kendrot, but Noseratio's solution worked perfectly.

I tried your suggestion but it's giving me an error `Extension methods must be defined in a non-generic static class` i tried creating a separate class but error persisted.

Comment: @BobMachine You are welcome. I've added how it should look with class in case somebody else will need it. It would be great if you could just test it and say if that worked - I've not tried that.

Comment: Sorry yesterday i was so tired i crashed...

I tested it, was able to compile fine but got an exception right after the `MemoryStream` init, this was the error 

`A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.ProtocolViolationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

An exception of type 'System.Net.ProtocolViolationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary`

Once again thanks for you help :)

Comment: @BobMachine Thanks for info. Then it should be little tuned for your purpose probably or maybe done via WebResponse. But there is no more need as you have working solution already :). Once again thanks for reply.

Comment: your welcome :)
Hope to see you around, you've been really cool.
I have also struggled at times, finding info for w8 but the not compatible with wp8.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use `Task.Factory.StartNew` with `async` methods. [Stephen Toub](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) and [Stephen Clearly](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) have explained why.

Second, if you're using `async-await`, then you can use the **~TaskAsync** methods of the [WebClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) with the [Microsoft Async NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) - given that you said it's for **Windows Phone 8**.

On a side note, you should always suffix your asynchronous methods with **Async** (or **TaskAsync** if not possible).

Given that, your code becomes:

```
public async Task<String> FileToBase64Async(String filePath)
{
    String convertedFile = "";

    var client = new WebClient();

    Task taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => client.OpenReadCompleted += async (object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e) =>
    {
        var buffer = await webclient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(filePath);
        convertedFile = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);

        return convertedFile;           
    }
}
```

But you would be better served with the new [HttpClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) that you can find on the [Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/).

And finally, you [should not block on async code in the UI thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: thanks for the tip, Noseratio's suggestion worked fine, i had just forgotten await on the function call